# Isn't String a [Char]?

Tags: haskell

As far as I know `String` is a `type` in Haskell:

```
type String = [Char]
```

Then I don't understand why the following code:

```
stringDecode :: String -> Maybe String
stringDecode s =
  let
    splitByColon x' = splitAt x' s
  in case findIndex (\b -> b == ':') s of
     (Just x)  -> snd (splitByColon x) 
     (Nothing) -> Nothing
```

Gives the following type error on compilation:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Maybe String'
            with actual type `[Char]'
Expected type: ([Char], Maybe String)
  Actual type: ([Char], [Char])
In the return type of a call of `splitByColon'
In the first argument of `snd', namely `(splitByColon x)'
```

**EDIT:** Fixed actually the problem was with the return expected of `Maybe String` whereas I returned  `[Char]` and returning `Just [Char]` did work.

Comment: Your function might be a bit simpler expressed as `stringDecode s = fmap (flip drop s) $ elemIndex ':' s`

Comment: Or maybe even simpler as `stringDecode = find ((== ':') . head) . init . tails`

Comment: If you answer your own question, please add an answer and don't edit the question's body.

Comment: -1 If you edit your code in place, you're breaking the whole question, as the code and the error message don't match up anymore.

Comment: @ThomasH haven't edited the code in place, the question and code remained untouched even after receiving the response.

Comment: +1 Ah, ok, then I got confused by your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your line `(Just x)  -> snd (splitByColon x)` is attempting to return a `String` instead of a `Maybe String`. You should replace that with `(Just x)  -> Just $ snd (splitByColon x)`

Comment: Thanks, just in that moment updating that question because I've seen it. :)